# How can we apply CSS stylings using Dart Language?

Tags: z-index, dart, dart-webui, dart-editor

I have got problem in applying z-index through dart. Whats the correct way to do this

```dart
var carousel = query(".carousel");
  var classList = [];
  carousel.children.forEach(
      (childElement) => childElement.classes.forEach(
         (className) => classList.add(className)
          ));
  for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
    query(classList[i]).style.zIndex+=1; //Need to increment z-index value for 
                                           the child divs incrementally
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

zIndex is a String so you can't increment it directly.

You can try this instead:

```dart
var elem = query(".${classList[i]}");
var newIndex = int.parse(elem.style.zIndex) + 1;
elem.style.zIndex = "${newIndex}";
```

Comment: I am Getting this console error "Exception: The null object does not have a getter 'style'."

Comment: Now its getting a Format Exception of Native Parse. What might be prob?

Comment: If zIndex is currently null, the code will not work. Initialize it first to "0".